# Android: change textview in loop

Tags: android, textview

I have some textviews in my activity and I have a do while Loop
and the task of the Loop is to Change some textviews but it didn't

No error in eclipse appears - toast runs with all Information

I tried it with

```
do{

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                 {
                public void run() 
                {
                    Random A0x = new Random();
                    int A0 = A0x.nextInt(15);
                    TextView TW_A0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.A0);
                     TW_A0.setText(Ans0[A0]);   



                    }
                 });
```

Or I tried it with

```
TextView TW_UZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UZ);
TW_UZ.setText(S+":"+M);
```

Any help?

Comment: You forgot your while

Comment: no need to initialize textview every time can be move outside the  loop

Comment: While it there - I didn't place it here ;)

Comment: @ChadWhite what is S and M?

Comment: I put initialize outside - nothing changes

Comment: s + m are just some strings second and minute

Comment: Try use Math.random() or synchronize your random object

Comment: I got similar problem with c# and second method worked like a charm

Comment: random works as it is - the toast Shows the desired text - but not the textview

Comment: did you tried to log output of A0 and check if it is different?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074570/android-loop-update-textview?rq=1

Comment: isn't similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
do{

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
             {
            public void run() 
            {
                Random A0x = new Random();
                int A0 = A0x.nextInt(15);
                TextView TW_A0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.A0);
                 TW_A0.setText(Ans0[A0]);

                 TW_A0.invalidate() // Tell text view to redraw its content   



                }
             });
```

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaah - I found the error - the loop is too fast - the textview Shows only the last entry - i Need a button for each Loop I think - thank you anyway maybe someone else find it useful